# How to Extract and compare values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as below:

```
Customer_ID Model Mileage
     A       X     100
     B       Y     200
```

Now I need  to compare the mileage and want to subtract Mileage2-Mileage1. So I split it into 2 different dataframe by using a function that gets customer info by customer ID.

```
df1 
Customer_ID Model Mileage
     A       X     100
df2
 Customer_ID Model Mileage
     B       Y     200
```

Now I want to subtract the Mileage values.

```
a=df2["Mileage"]-df1["Mileage"]
print(a)
```

But instead of the subtracted value (200-100)=100 I get the following output:

```
200   NaN
100   NaN
Name: Mileage, dtype: float64
```

How can I extract the values and subtract or compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `equal()`:

```
df1['Mileage'].equals(df2['Mileage'])
```

will return `True` or `False`

Note: this would compare the whole of the two columns.

If you intend to compare single value-data, you could also look for `np.where()`:

```
df['result'] = np.where((df1['Mileage'] == df2['Mileage']),True, False)
```